# Same style for all project github pages?

Tags: github, themes, jekyll, github-pages, hakyll

I would like all my project pages to have the same custom style. But for now I only see that every project page can be configured separately (choosing default theme from Setting of the project or creating `gh-pages` branch with the source files).

Is there any way to archive what I want? For example, to write custom style in my `username.github.io` repo and all project could use that styles to create pages under `username.github.io/projectname` with the provided custom styles.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem to link `username.github.io/style.css` from any of your project repository.

Answer (score 0):

If your `username.github.io` repo is public, then you could access the styling file(s) from any other repo.

In `username.github.io`, let's say there's a file `username.github.io/styling/main.css`. In your layouts for any other projects, you can link to the file like a regular external css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/username.github.io/styling/main.css">
```

`raw.githubusercontent.com` has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*`. It accepts all incoming CORS requests, so you don't have to worry about CORS issues. Also, `<link>` tags get the respective files using `GET` requests, which don't trigger CORS preflight requests.

Comment: If one use jekyll, files at `raw.githubusercontent.com` will be the source version and not the generated one. Plus : `raw.githubusercontent.com` is not returning the correct content-type.